# How can I absolutely position this dropdown in an overflow scroll parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu in a parent `div` that has a fixed `height` and has `overflow: auto` on it. I would like my menu to extend over the edge of this parent when opened. At the moment, it increases the height of the parent instead.

See [this reduced test case](https://codepen.io/shainanigans-1472169587/pen/QXdaVW) in codepen, or the code here:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button id="btn" class="btn" type="button">Click me</button>
    <div id="menu" class="menu">I should stick out of the parent, but instead I make the parent scroll</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.parent {
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center
}
.btn {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  &.show {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

(The JS simply toggles the `show` class on the dropdown and isn't relevant.)

I've tried wrapping the dropdown in another `div` and putting pretty much every value of overflow on it and the parent known to mankind—but no luck.

I would really like to avoid moving my menu outside of the parent and positioning it with JS; surely there is a CSS solution for this (I hope!)

Anyone have any clues?

*Updated to add that I need the dropdown to exist in the normal document flow as in my actual application there can be many of these dropdowns one after the other in the parent `div`.

Comment: Can you replace the SCSS with the compiled CSS and make a working snippet in order to debug?

Comment: @Nimsrules did you have a look at my codepen link?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hack that you can do. Not sure if it is the right way of doing it, but it works.

One thing you have to keep in mind is that if you scroll, the menu **WILL NOT** move so you have to implement the code to listen for scroll event on the document and either hide the menu or move it accordingly.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function openMenu() {

  var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  
  var top = btn.offsetTop;
  var left = btn.offsetLeft;
  var height = btn.offsetHeight;
  
  
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  menu.style.top = top + height +'px';
  menu.style.left = left + 'px';
  
  menu.classList.toggle('show');
};
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  overflow: auto;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.menu.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>Button must remain in document flow to coexist with other elements in the parent.</span>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button id="btn" class="btn" type="button">Click me</button>
    <div id="menu" class="menu">I should stick out of the parent, but instead I make the parent scroll.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @RBCunhaDesign—I'm aware I can do it with JS but was hoping for a CSS only solution (as mentioned in the post).